# Python - collecting data from Twitter API and storing it in an SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter

I am trying to build a Python script that collects data from Twitter's Stream API and then I want to store it in an SQLite database. 
I need to save this data including:

• Tweet ID 
• Tweet Text 
• Created at 
• Location 
• Geo coordinates 
• Number of followers for the user 
• Number of friends

I managed to stream tweets and also I created a database. How can I save the data I get from Twitter API to that database?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please provide the code you tried, in a minimal example so we can understand what is blocking you https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you! The thing is I have not written a single line of code as I am a month in to Python. I need the steps to start with. I am aware that I need to use Tweepy(?).

Comment: You can start here : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/ or there : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info . You can read some tutorials on the Twitter API (https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/), then on SQLite : https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html . Try some code and if it does not work you may start a new topic with some specific question.

Comment: You don't need to use tweepy as there are many ways to use the Twitter API in python. You may use tweepy as it may be convenient for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll start now.